# How to make <ul> collapse to width of floated <li>s?

Tags: html, css

I'd like to create a list of "tiles" that, for all practical purposes, looks like a `<table>`, but I don't want to use tables because the number of columns might change based on the size of the content in the tiles, and I want it to be fluid.

I gave each tile a border-right and border-bottom, and I gave the parent container of the tiles a border-top and border-left. The problem is the border-top of the parent container extends all the way to the right of its parent container instead of stopping after the last tile in the first row. How would I go about eliminating that extra line extending off to the upper right corner? Or how would I go about achieving this effect a better way?

[Preview Here](http://www.toprival.com/temp/tiles/)

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title></title>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <style type="text/css">
            * {
                margin: 0;
                padding: 0;
            }

            body {
                background-color: #DDD;
                font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
            }

            #wrapper {
                background-color: #FFF;
                width: 800px;
                margin: 0 auto;
                padding: 20px;
            }

            .clearfix:after {
                content: "";
                display: table;
                clear: both;
            }

            .tiles {
                list-style: none;
                padding: 0;
                border: 1px solid #000;
                border-right: 0;
                border-bottom: 0;
            }

            .tile {
                color: #333;
                width: 140px;
                height: 140px;
                overflow: hidden;
                padding: 20px 10px 20px 20px;
                border: 1px solid #000;
                border-top: 0;
                border-left: 0;
                display: inline-block;
                float: left;
            }

            .tile h2 {
                margin: 0;
                font-size: 1.25em;
            }

            .tile p {
                margin: 0 0 1em 0;
                font-size: .75em;
            }

            .tile p:last-child {
                margin: 0;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="wrapper">
            <ul class="tiles clearfix">
                <li class="tile">
                    <h2>Tile Title</h2>
                    <p>Blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah</p>
                </li>

                <li class="tile">
                    <h2>Tile Title</h2>
                    <p>Blah blah blah blah blah blah blah</p>
                </li>

                <li class="tile">
                    <h2>Tile Title</h2>
                    <p>Blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah</p>

                    <p>Blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah</p>
                </li>

                <li class="tile">
                    <h2>Tile Title</h2>
                    <p>Blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah</p>

                    <p>blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah</p>
                </li>

                <li class="tile">
                    <h2>Tile Title</h2>
                    <p>Blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah</p>
                </li>

                <li class="tile">
                    <h2>Tile Title</h2>
                    <p>Blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah</p>
                </li>

                <li class="tile">
                    <h2>Tile Title</h2>
                    <p>Blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah</p>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: I think you could get away with dropping the border for the `ul` and instead apply a full border to each `li`. Then, apply a negative margin for the right and bottom of the tiles, and that will ensure the borders overlap.

Comment: Off-topic: using `display:inline-block` with floating is useless, because it will behave like `block`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use negative margins to overlap duplicate borders:

```
.tiles {
    border: none;
    margin-bottom: 1px;
    margin-right: 1px;
}

.tile {
    border: 1px solid #333;
    margin: 0 -1px -1px 0;
}
```

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/Gpw3M/)

Answer (score 1):

Try to give your ul a width. It is 684px in your case.

```
<ul class="tiles clearfix" style="width: 684px;">
```

But there is absolutely better designs for your logic.

Answer (score 0):

Here have a look.

http://jsfiddle.net/39MW6/1/

The inner borders are a slightly thicker but it works.

added `border-top: 0;` to the `.tiles {}`